# Restored TFS 2012 raises TF30063: You are not authorized to access

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to restore a TFS 2012 installation from an old server on a new machine. Everything worked fine during the installation of TFS. The team project collections are displayed properly in the administration console and some features like change URLs work fine.

Simply, I cannot connect to the server from the browser or administer Group Membership in administration console. It prompts me every time to provide login credentials, although I'm logged in as Administrator. Providing the Administrator credentials does not help as it keeps throwing

```
TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://localhost:8080/tfs
```

The same applies when I try a remote connection from my regular windows developer machine.

Both old and new server are Win2008R2. They are not members of a domain. Old and new SqlServer (hostes on the same machine as TFS) are both SQL-Server 2012.

I went through this description on how to restore the application tier:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd793167.aspx
(Restore an Application-Tier Server)

I restored the required databases via SQL Server Management Studio, installed TFS and started the Application-Tier only wizard as described in the guide. Then I configured local service as the account for TFSService.

The interesting part is that if I restore TFS on another physical machine or virtual machine using the same instructions, everything works fine connecting locally and remote. The issue seems to relate on this specific new server (virtual server). BTW I noticed this server hosts some additional IIS web sites, but none of them is blocking port 8080 reserved by TFS.

Comment: Thank you for the info Dave, I've installed the patch you mentioned, with no effect. Trying to browse to the TFS site or change group membership in Admin Console keeps throwing the earlier mentioned error after prompting me to provide login credentials. It's strange behaviour since I could restore the databases on other servers without this patch. It seems to be something particular to this single server

Comment: Based on your statement that it works when restored to other machines, it does sound like something specific to the configuration of the machine. Maybe the IIS logs would shed some light on it. Also, check the Windows application event log to see if there are any errors that would indicate what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not figure out the reason why this procedure does not work on that specific server. I decided to use the detach/attach path to transfer the TFS data.

1. Install the patch on the old server, just to avoid possible loss of permissions (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2803625)
2. Detach the team project collections from the old server in TFS admin console
3. Backup the team collection databases in SSMS
4. Install TFS 2012 on the new server, closing the automatically started wizard immediately after installation (You can restart it once again later).
5. Apply the TFS patch on the new server
6. Start TFS admin console, click on Application Tier and went through the configuration wizard (choosed basic configuration for my purposes). This procedure creates a new configuration database.
7. Restore the dbs on the new server in SSMS
8. Attach them on the new server in TFS admin console

This worked great for me although I cannot explain exactly what went wrong with my first approach which has been proven so many times on other machines. I'm assuming some sort of incompatibility between TFS_Configuration database and the hosting system.